# Shadows on three sides only with multiple inset box-shadows and alpha transparency

Tags: html, css

The goal is to have an element with a sublte inset `box-shadow` where the bottom edge is not affected by any shadow. I tried playing around with the values of the shadow but no luck.

To matters worse, the colors have transparency which means that I cannot simply overlap the triangle with the element as to hide the line of the shadow. Any ideas?

[image] [image]

```css
.nav {
  background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0,.5);
}
.item {
  display:inline-block; margin-left:100px;
  position:relative; border-left: rgba(0,0,0,.8); border-right: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
  padding:5px 30px; background-color:rgba(10,36,53,.1);
  box-shadow: inset 0 10px 20px 2px rgba(10,36,53,.1),
    inset 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.1),
    inset  0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

.triangle {
  border-top: 15px solid rgba(2,7,10,.55);
  border-left: 15px solid transparent; border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  position: absolute; bottom: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px; left:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <div class="item">
    Hello World
    <div class="triangle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create in photoshop what you want it to look like?

Comment: what about something like this **http://jsfiddle.net/mturjak/x1envwuo/** using a bit of a shadow vertical offset

Comment: @MartinTurjak that works nicely. thanks. add as an answer and i'll accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use vertical offset on the shadow ... something like this could work:

```
inset 0px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mturjak/x1envwuo/)

and you can in addition use negative values on `spread radius` if the offset makes the shadow stick out too far ... something like this:

```
inset 0px 3px 3px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
```